# Чем отличается addEventListener от onclick?

Tags: javascript

чем отличается addEventListener от onclick ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`onclick`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick) - это *свойство* конкретного DOM элемента. Значением этого свойства является обработчик события `click`, а именно - конкретная функция.

[`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) - это метод, который **добавляет** обработчик события. Может быть вызван несколько раз, в этом случае будет добавлено *несколько* обработчиков. Позволяет указывать фазу события, на которую добавляется обработчик, а так же имеет дополнительные настройки.

Немного на примере:

```js
btn1.onclick = function() {
  console.log('first onclick');
}
btn1.onclick = function() {
  console.log('second onclick');
}

btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('first addEventListener');
})
btn2.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('second addEventListener');
})
```

```html
<button id="btn1">onclick</button>
<button id="btn2">addEventListener</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо,а можно попонятней?

Comment: *Садитесь в кружок, ребятишки, До ужина есть полчаса. Сейчас расскажу я вам сказку Про рыцарей и чудеса.*

Comment: @Grundy Мои поздравления с 50к.

Comment: @ЛаврикКан, а что конкретно непонятно? что свойство присваивается, а метод вызывается?

Comment: Как понять что addEventListener() может вызван несколько раз?,разве onclick нельзя вызвать несколько раз на пример при нажатии на кнопку?Или я не правильно понял?Вы написали "Может быть вызван несколько раз, в этом случае будет добавлено несколько обработчиков." но в onclick вроде тоже можно добавить несколько обработчиков событий!?И вы сказали "Позволяет указывать фазу события, на которую добавляется обработчик, а так же имеет дополнительные настройки." а разве onclick не позволяет указывать фазу?например при  клике или при наведении?Вот что мне не понятно!

Comment: @ЛаврикКан, _но в onclick вроде тоже можно добавить несколько обработчиков событий_ - а ты попробуй добавить несколько обработчиков ;-)

Comment: попробовал,все работало,только что проверил

Comment: @ЛаврикКан, покажи как попробовал. _а разве onclick не позволяет указывать фазу?например при клике или при наведении?_ - у событий есть две фазы: фаза захвата, фаза всплытия. А при наведении и при клике это **разные** события

Comment: next.onclick=function () {img.src=i===mass.length-1?mass[i=0]:mass[i+=1];}
    next.onmouseover=function () {next.style.color='red';}

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84053/discussion-between-grundy-and--).