# Писать проще, иначе

Tags: javascript

```
class Target {
    constructor(val) {
         this.el = val
    }
    on(e, f) { 
        typeof e == 'string' ? 
            this.el.addEventListener(e, f) 
        : 
            e.forEach(i => this.el.addEventListener(i, f)); 
            return this
    }

}
new Target(el).on(['slsh','slh2'], t => {
    //Тут выполняем код который срабатывает при событие, которое повесили на элемент
});
```

Вот интересно, возможно не писать каждый раз new Target(el), то есть иначе написать.
К примеру как нибудь так $(el)? Как такого добиться?

Answer (score 0):

В случае с классом писать `new` обязательно.

Чтобы писать `$(el)` достаточно завести функцию-обертку:

```
function $(el){
    return new Target(el);
}
```

Comment: this.el.addEventListener(e, f), возможно прописать так же  как со стрелочными функциями (this.el['on'+e] = f)

Comment: Не понимаю как это сделать...

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, не понял вопроса

Comment: Вместо this.el.addEventListener(e, f)

Comment: this.el.onmouseenter = e => {  }

Comment: Обычно так пишу, хотелось бы и в классе аналогично прописать.

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов, а ты знаешь чем отличается установка обработчика через `.addEventListener` и через свойство?

Comment: Нет, в чем? Никогда не задавался данным вопросом

Comment: @ДмитрийВарзанов [Чем отличается addEventListener от onclick?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889024/186999)

Comment: То есть через on можем повесить только одно событие на элемент. Или только одно схожее событие, то есть если повесить два клика, сработает последние. А через addEventListener, повесив 2 события клика, сработают оба.

Comment: Мне та конечно, желательно чтобы срабатывало только последнее повешенное события. Есть моменты, когда одно событие необходимо вешать дважды. Повесив его второй раз, через addEventListener, сработают оба, значит будет выше нагрузка про процессор пользователя?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136750/discussion-between-grundy-and--).